# What sports are played on a square (besides a given list of exceptions)?

Tags: rules, venues

As part of a mathematics class, I have to identify sports played on a square, not rectangular, playing surface. For example, basketball and football are both played on a rectangular field.

The following sports are not allowed as answers for this assignment: jiu jitsu, taekwondo, boxing, wrestling, four square, baseball, and chess. It must be a physical, contact sport.

Comment: I don't understand how this can be part of a mathematics class.

Comment: Here's some hints: jiu jitsu, taekwondo, boxing and wrestling are all in one category of sports. Find some more sports in that category. Next: if chess counts as a sport, then look at similar games. There's also a sport very similar to baseball.

Comment: @Bernhard, its because the teacher was telling us about how a square is always a rectangle but a rectangle is not always a square or vice versa, I forget which way it is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In cricket, the pitch that is played on is prepared on a square of carefully cultivated grass, it is also sometimes called the cricket square.

Comment: It is by name but the playable pitch is rectangular. The "square" comes from having a number of rectangular pitches placed side by side so that they have time to recover / grow grass and prepared for future matches

Comment: The ground in cricket is often a circle or odd ellipse. The pitch is only a small part of it.